# cordova 4 android back button error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview

I'm using Cordova 4.0.0 and Android 4.4.2.

Everytime Android's virtual back button is pressed, I get an error:

unimplemented WebView method onKeyDOwn called from: android.webkit.WebView.onKeyDown(WebView.java:2169)

And then it pops up an alert with jQuery unknown nodeType (I have jquery in my asset/www).

I tried to override onKeyDown in CordovaApp but it doesn't seem to do anything.

`@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }`

I'm a little stumped why says not implemented but pops up a DOM related error. 
I searched everywhere can couldn't find an answer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same here OMG ... and the solutions below don't seem to work so far. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown(ev){
    // Something
}
```

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but is now resolved. Try:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {  history.go(-1); navigator.app.backHistory(); }
```